# How to pass variables as parameters to subreports using SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I am working on an SSRS project which has main report and sub reports. To the subreport, I would like to pass a variable that uses stuff sql syntax. This variable will have comma separated values. I would like to know how to pass variables as parameters to subreports.

Answer (score 1):

If you go to the Action tab in the properties window, there is an area at the bottom which you can assign the parameters to be passed to the next report. If you want to pass an existing parameter, you would send

> =Parameters!MyParameterName.Value

as the value.

I'm not sure what "stuff sql syntax" means, but you can pretty much put whatever you want into the value field as a string and parse it in the next report.

[image: Screen Shot]